# Cannot calculate min in datetime column

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

When i try to group by 'loan_id' column and aggregate some other columns such as 'Next Installment Date'

```
installments_df.groupby(['loan_id']).aggregate({'amount': 'max', 'installment_number': 'max', 'Remaining_Tenor': 'sum', **'Next Installment Date': 'min'**})
```

It gives me this error :
'<=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'

i casted the column 'Next Installment Date' to datetime to make sure that it is not a string
put still shows same error.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp data type can't use with int/float type data...
before doing "<=" (condition) convert Timestamp  into int/float value ....

Comment: i am trying to convert it to 'int' like this:
installments_data = installments_df.groupby(['loan_id']).aggregate({'amount': 'max',  int('Next Installment Date'): 'min'})
but it shows this error :
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Next Installment Date'

Comment: give me full code if you don't mind ? i will help

Comment: installments_df = pd.DataFrame(installments)

def get_next_ins_date(row):
    if row['status'] != 'paid':
        date_min = row['due_date']
    else:
        date_min = 0
    return date_min 

installments_df['Next Installment Date'] = installments_df.apply(get_next_ins_date, axis= 1)
installments_data = installments_df.groupby(['loan_id']).aggregate({'Remaining_Tenor': 'sum', 'Next Installment Date': 'min'})

Comment: it depends on a csv file but i can't share it.. Can you help me with this shared code?
Sure .. thank you in any case